# rows are lineary independent $\Rightarrow$ detA$\not= 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to know how to continue a proof of a standard statement: Let $A\in K^{n\times n}$, K is a field, $\begin{pmatrix} 
 a_{j,1}, ...,a_{j,n}
 \\
\end{pmatrix}=v_j$ the j-th row of A.   $\text{det}(A)\not= 0\iff $ the rows of A are lineary independent. 
I only stuck on $"\Leftarrow$": We assume that if $\lambda_1v_1+..+\lambda_nv_n=0$ $\Rightarrow\; \lambda_i=0\; \forall\; i=1,..,n$. Now it is $\text{det}(\lambda_1v_1+..+\lambda_nv_n)=\lambda_1\text{det}(\begin{pmatrix} 
 a_{1,1}, ...,a_{1,n}
 \\
\end{pmatrix})+...+\lambda_n\text{det}(\begin{pmatrix} 
 a_{n,1}, ...,a_{n,n}
 \\
\end{pmatrix})$
Now if $\exists \lambda_i\not=0 $, we know that $\lambda_1v_1+..+\lambda_nv_n\not= 0$ So one of these summands is $\not=0$ but I don't know how to complete the proof.

Ok, forget everything. How to prove $\Leftarrow$?

Comment: If $v_i$ is a row vector, then $\det(v_i)$ is undefined.  The $\det$ function acts on matrices (or pseudoscalars) -- not row vectors.  Also $\det(A+B) \ne \det(A) + \det(B)$ in general.

Comment: Ok, I saw this notation in a book and it cofused me. I don't know how to prove this direction:(